# Boot endless loop

Tags: system-installation, boot

I want to install elementary OS and try it out but it never reaches the GUI the background appears for a fraction of a second and it then goes into an endless loop mouse cursor bottom right and back to a blank screen. It just keeps doing that forever. I had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and it never was resolved, 18.10 is fine on the latest download. The graphics card is an ATI / AMD RS740 [Radeon 2100] built into the PC a Packard Bell UTOW-BEN. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Colin

Comment: I am using Manjaro currently on the same pc and it is fine with no display issues.  Any Ubuntu / Debian based distro gives issues with the display.

Comment: I see, and as you know elementary OS is based on Ubuntu LTS releases. Please let me know updated situation.